# What does "bits" directory stand for in glibc project?

Tags: header, glibc, libc

I found out headers under "bits" directory are internal headers which general headers include.

Then what does the name "bits" stand for?

Comment: It refers to "bits" as in the idiom ["bits and pieces"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bits%20and%20pieces), meaning a collection of various small things that are not directly related to each other.